# python not allowing to assign float to nan value

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Iam trying to find the mean, but ignoring the values which will give zero. But getting a issue `'float' object does not support item assignment.`

This is my code

```
        for i in range(len(rvector)):
                c+= l1[i]*l2[i]
        cosine = c / float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5)
        cosine[cosine == 0] = np.nan
        print("similarity: ", cosine)
        mean = np.nanmean(cosine, axis=0)
        print("Mean: ", mean)
```

Can someone help me to correct it and write the correct code.

Comment: You calculate a single number "cosine" which can't be used with item assignment `[...]`. What is "cosine" meant to be?

Comment: This happens because `c`, and therefore `cosine`, is not a Numpy array, but a single `float` value. You can determine this by *reading the error message*. We can't tell you what is wrong with the code before that because you have not shown us the initial assignment to `c`, nor have you shown us what `l1` and `l2` are.